# How do i convert my merge sort implementation to funtional-style using java 8?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

Below is my implementation for merge sort algorithm

```
private void mergeSort(Integer[] t,int low, int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        mergeSort(t,low,mid);
        mergeSort(t,mid+1,high);

        merge(t,low,mid,high);
    }
}

private void merge(Integer[] t, int low, int mid, int high){
    Integer[] temp = t.clone();
    int i=low,j=mid+1,k=low;
    while(i<=mid && j<=high)
    {
        temp[k++] = t[i] < t[j] ? t[i++] : t[j++];
    }
    while(i<=mid)
        temp[k++] = t[i];
    while(j<=high)
        temp[k++] = t[j];

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));

 }
```

I was considering if i could modify it to pure functional style like using java 8. Somewhere close to what how we do in Scala.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855746/understanding-when-and-how-to-use-java-8-lambdas/24855915#24855915) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Eran that is one *crazy* `BinaryOperator` :) plus one there for the effort!

Comment: @Eugene Thanks :) It was fun playing with.

Comment: @Eran Thats indeed something i was looking for.